# Detect Crawler and load Template from server

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, web-crawler, facebook-share

I am new in VUE JS.

I have project detail page. For social sharing there will be dynamic values for meta tags e.g `og:title` or `og:image`. I am able to set the meta tag values. But when I check on facebook debugger it took the old/default meta content. From this [link](https://github.com/declandewet/vue-meta/issues/133) i get to know that need to check the user agent and then the load template accordingly.

But how we can do it in VUE JS?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dynamically set meta tags like `og:title` or `og:image`  you may want to consider doing it from backend code so that the dynamic tags are in place when the html is sent to the browser.  The reason for this is that some crawlers do not run javascript code.  For any crawler that does not run javascript code, setting such meta tags via a clientside library like Vue.js will not affect what the crawler sees since it will only see the html as it existed when originally streamed from the server.